# Tooltips not appearing for secondary plot

Tags: altair

I’m curious why the tooltips of the 2nd plot (point_max) are not appearing in the final plot though the data points themselves are fine.

The tooltips for the first plot (rule_q) are active in the combined plot and when plotting ‘point_max’ on its own the tooltips do appear normally.

Even if the tooltips for ‘rule_q’ are removed, those for the ‘point_max’ chart never show up in the combined plot.

The relevant code:

```
                base = alt.Chart(yrDF,title=titStr).transform_calculate(
                    color = 'datum.Complete > 0.95 ? "#f4be2b" : "lightgray"'
                    ).interactive()

                rule_q= base.mark_rule(size=3).encode(
                    alt.X('date:T'),
                    alt.Y('meanMinus:Q'),
                    alt.Y2('meanPlus:Q'),
                    color=alt.Color('color:N',scale=None),
                    href='urls:N',
                    tooltip=[
                        alt.Tooltip('date:T', title='Date',format='%b %d, %Y'),
                    ]
                )

                point_max= alt.Chart(yrDF).mark_point(size=12).encode(
                    x=alt.X('date:T'),
                    y=alt.Y('max:Q'),
                    tooltip=[
                        alt.Tooltip('max:Q',format='.0f')
                    ]
                )

                chart= rule_q + point_max
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Vega-Lite; see https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/5732

A potential workaround is to add `interactive()` separately to each chart, rather than adding it to the base chart. See also [Altair - Unable to get tooltips for one layer in a line chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59671294/altair-unable-to-get-tooltips-for-one-layer-in-a-line-chart/).