# altair tooltip layered chart not showing on mac screen

Tags: python, pandas, altair

The following code works as expected except on the native macbook pro screen the tooltips wont reveal the data.  If I move the chrome tab to either of my secondary monitors the tooltips display normally.  Following that if I move the chrome pane/tab back to the mbPro screen the tooltips continue to work

mbp 2.2 i7, 2015 retina 15 inch, osx10.13
pandas 1.5.3

altair 4.1.0

```
  # visualize the spectral centroids - an intuition of the spectral content
    cent_plot = alt.Chart(cent_df).mark_line(clip=True, color='red', point=True).encode(
        alt.X('index:Q', title='Frames (2048 samp,@ 44.1 khz)'),
        alt.Y('spectral_cent_freq:Q', title='Frequency (Hz)' ),
        tooltip=alt.Tooltip(['spectral_cent_freq:Q'],
        title= 'Frequency')).properties(
        title = "Spectral Centroid w running Mean ("+")", 
        width=1000, height=600).interactive()
    
    cent_cma = alt.Chart(cent_df).mark_circle(clip=True, color='green').encode(
        alt.X('index:Q'),
        alt.Y('cma:Q' ),
        tooltip=alt.Tooltip(['cma:Q'], title= 'Running Mean Frequency')).properties(
        width=1000, height=600).interactive()
    
    cent_layer = (cent_plot + cent_cma)
    cent_layer.show()
```

Has anyone else seen this issue?
Thanks

[Altair - Unable to get tooltips for one layer in a line chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59671294/altair-unable-to-get-tooltips-for-one-layer-in-a-line-chart)

I looked at this post and I am not certain the issue is related

Comment: The best way to get help is to provide a [mre] and try it in the vega editor (click the three dots menu of the chart). If it doesn't work there file an issue in the vegalite repo

Comment: Yes I will update the code above with a basic df for proof.  Sorry all I'm still pretty new to the coding world.    I still am uncertain if S.O. is the correct forum soliciting the community on concerns of this nature.    I have another clue that it is hardware specific and I think somehow related to a usb docking station at work because I attempted to recreate the issue from my home office and the symptoms no longer occur (tooltip data is displayed correctly).   I will look again at the issue there and attempt to uncover more detail.  Thanks

Comment: No need to apologize, SO is a good place for your question. In general trying to reproduce the issue in a simpler example can be very helpful for yourself to understand what might be going wrong and easier for others to help out with. If it turns out to truly be an issue with Vega-Lite and some specific hardware version of your laptop, it could be worthwhile posting it on their issue tracker.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with the hardware configuration that I encountered it on.  I struggled with this visualization 'nuisance' last week while trying to make a deadline so I am not sure what kind of anomaly could have caused it .  Should I suggest the issue be closed (I can't due to my status) or what is the best way to proceed in the off chance I can stumble upon the symptoms again?  Thanks

Comment: Thanks for following up @phidelity, I suggested for the issue to be closed based on your description and it can be when another user with sufficient permission reviews it.